# Column Re-order in Grid Component of Kendo UI for Angular

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

Can anyone tell me if it's possible to re-order the columns by drag-drop using Kendo UI for Angular components?

I could see this feature in Kendo UI for jquery.

Answer (score 1):

The [grid column reordering feature](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/columns/reordering/)  was released with R1 2018 in January.